# email input works fine but when inputting a password that contains White spaces the output is false error in {password_pattern=".{10,20}";}

Tags: java

I tried to replace the user input with including the password with the same pattern in the code and had no problems.

**other question:** what is the sign of a white space in java regex?

**note:** I am new to java so my code might seem a little messed-up

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String email_pattern = "\\w{7,20}@(gmail|Hotmail|yahoo)\\.com"; // email pattern String password_pattern=".{10,20}"; //password pattern`(problem in this statement)
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    String email;
    String password;


    System.out.println("Welcome to my site"); //
    System.out.print("Enter your email: ");
    email = s.next(); //email input by user
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(email_pattern);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(email);
    if (m.matches()) {
        System.out.print("\nEnter your password: ");
        password = s.next(); //password input by user
        Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile(password_pattern);
        Matcher m2 = p2.matcher(password);
        if (m2.matches()) {

            System.out.print("\n You are logged in");
        } else {
            System.out.print("\n" + m2.matches); // outputs the matching result if the password has a wrong format
        }
    } else {
        System.out.print("\nWrong email format please re-enter your email");
    }
}

//output problem in password matching with white spaces
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has one problem, and that is with java function, not regex pattern please correct that one to solve your problem:

replace each `s.next()` with

```
s.nextLine()
```

because s.next() method returns the `next token` means input word by word with space as the separator of next token.

check out the implementation of scanner.next(): https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_next.htm

Answer (score 0):

Just put the regex for both emailId and password.There are many way to put regex for email and password. Here is a simple example with description.

**Regex for email =** `^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)* @[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$;`

**Description**

```
^                   #   start of the line
[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+   #   must start with string in the bracket [ ], must contains one or more (+)
(                   #   start of group #1
  \\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+ #   follow by a dot "." and string in the bracket [ ], must contains one or more (+)
)*                  #   end of group #1, this group is optional (*)
@                   #   must contains a "@" symbol
[A-Za-z0-9-]+       #   follow by string in the bracket [ ], must contains one or more (+)
(                   #   start of group #2 - first level TLD checking
\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+     #   follow by a dot "." and string in the bracket [ ], must contains one or more (+)
)*                  #   end of group #2, this group is optional (*)
(                   #   start of group #3 - second level TLD checking
\\.[A-Za-z]{2,}     #   follow by a dot "." and string in the bracket [ ], with minimum length of 2
)                   #   end of group #3
$                   #   end of the line
```

**Regex for password =** `((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%]).{10,20});`

**Description**

```
(               # Start of group
  (?=.*\d)      # must contains one digit from 0-9
  (?=.*[a-z])   # must contains one lowercase characters
  (?=.*[A-Z])   # must contains one uppercase characters
  (?=.*[@#$%])  # must contains one special symbols in the list "@#$%"
  .             # match anything with previous condition checking
  {10,20}       # length at least 10 characters and maximum of 20
)               # End of group
```

Now complete code would be like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String email_pattern = "^[A-Za-z0-9+_.-]+@(.+)$"; 
    String password_pattern = "((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%]).{10,20})";

    String email;
    String password;

    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in); 

    System.out.println("Welcome to my site"); /
    System.out.print("Enter your email: ");
    email=s.next(); 
    Pattern p=Pattern.compile(email_pattern);
    Matcher m=p.matcher(email);
    if(m.matches()){
        System.out.print("\nEnter your password: ");
        password=s.next(); 
        Pattern p2=Pattern.compile(password_pattern);
        Matcher m2=p2.matcher(password);
        if(m2.matches()){
            System.out.print("\n You are logged in");
        }else{
            System.out.print("\n"+m2.matches);
        }
    }else{
        System.out.print("\nWrong email format please re-enter your email");
    }
}
```